# SPARK SQL (1.5.1) connect to Oracle and write to Avro

Tags: jdbc, avro, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql to connect to oracle databse and getting data as dataframes. I would like to write this retrieved data into avro file. While writing to avro I am seeing multiple issues, could you help us.

Here is the code -

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
    .options(Map( "driver"->"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", 
    "url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@host/service"
    , "numPartitions" -> "1", "dbtable"-> "
    (Select * from schema.table WHERE STAGE_NUM <=39 and 
    guid='I284ba1f9cdba11dea82ab9f4ee295c21')"))
    .load()
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("Outputfile")
```

Dependencies that are there in my project -

`<dependency><br>  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId><br>  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId><br>  <version>1.5.1</version><br></dependency><br><dependency><br>  <groupId>com.databricks</groupId><br>  <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId><br>  <version>2.0.1</version><br></dependency><br><dependency><br>  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId><br>  <artifactId>avro</artifactId><br>  <version>1.7.7</version><br></dependency><br><dependency><br>  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId><br>  <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId><br>  <version>1.7.7</version><br></dependency>`

Here is the exception information -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select

If I use  - `df.write.avro("headnotes")`, I get the following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldDefault from class com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$convertStructToAvro$1

Comment: did you resolve this?